# MySQL view performance

Tags: mysql, performance, view

I have a table for about 100,000 users in it.

First Case:

```
explain select state, count(*) as cnt from users where state = 'ca'
```

When I do an explain plan for the above query I get the cost as 5200

Second Case:

```
Create or replace view vw_users as select state, count(*) as cnt from users

Explain select cnt from vw_users where state = 'ca'
```

When I do an explain plan on the second query I get the cost as 100,000.

How does the where clause in the view work? Is the where clause applied after the view retrieves all the rows? How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Your view definition is missing the group by clause.

Comment: If you can't use the merge algorithm, here's a work around I found helpful: [Workaround for the performance problems of temptable views](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/05/19/a-workaround-for-the-performance-problems-of-temptable-views/)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's about the [view algorithm](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-algorithms.html) that's been used.

The **merge** algorithm works well most table indexes and whatnot - the **temptable** algorithm doesn't - in many cases your indexes will just be flat-out not used at all.

And there's lots of crap that merge doesn't support

> MERGE  cannot be used if the view
>   contains any of the following
>   constructs:
>
> ```
> * Aggregate functions (SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), COUNT(), and so forth)
> * DISTINCT
> * GROUP BY
> * HAVING
> * LIMIT
> * UNION or UNION ALL
> * Subquery in the select list
> * Refers only to literal values (in this case, there is no underlying table)
> ```

Comment: Peter, Thanks for the input. I have a count(*) in my view. So i can't use merge. Right now i didn't specify any algorithm type.

So the best way can be use a stored procedure instead of a view ?

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to go for a stored procedure here - or just a straight-up subquery.