# mysql view index

Tags: mysql, view, indexing

Do you know index can be added to MySQL view?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have an indexed view in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244226/is-it-possible-to-have-an-indexed-view-in-mysql)

Comment: MySQL doesn't support materialized views.  The view support is rather limited, in comparison to other databases.

Answer (score 6):

Sadly, you can't. You can index the tables the view is based on.

Also, see this question: [Is it possible to have an indexed view in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244226/is-it-possible-to-have-an-indexed-view-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

For more information about indexes and MySQL view performance, [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760475).

Answer (score 0):

However, you can use some tricks. Add custom_id field to view and put value of "hash" of another unique field in same row :D

In my case i combine category id and article id