# Select query 2-3 times faster than view

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

This query run alone:

```
SELECT 
    -- lots of columns 
FROM 
    table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2
        ON t2.[userid] = t1.[userid]
    LEFT JOIN table3 t3
        ON t1.[orderid] = t3.[orderid]
    LEFT JOIN table4 t4
        ON t4.[orderitemlicenseid] = t3.[orderitemlicenseid]
    LEFT JOIN table5 t5
        ON t1.[orderid] = t5.[orderid]
    LEFT JOIN table6 t6
        ON t5.[transactionid] = t6.[transactionid]
    LEFT JOIN table7 t7
        ON t7.[transactionid] = t5.[transactionid]
    LEFT JOIN table8 t8
        ON t8.[voucherid] = t7.[voucherid]
    LEFT JOIN table9 t9
        ON t8.[voucherid] = t9.[voucherid]
    LEFT JOIN table10 t10
        ON t10.[vouchergroupid] = t9.[vouchergroupid]
        AND t10.[territoryid] = t2.[territoryid]
    LEFT JOIN table11 t11
        ON t11.[voucherid] = t8.[voucherid]
    LEFT JOIN table12 t12
        ON t12.[orderid] = t1.[orderid]
GROUP BY 
    t5.[transactionid]
```

Takes about 2.5 seconds to finish. When I save it to a view and run it as:

SELECT * FROM viewName;

It takes 7 seconds to finish.

What is the reason and how can I make the view faster?

Comment: Why do you repeatedly double-open and double-close your parenthesis?

Comment: Are you adding any `WHERE` conditions to your view?

Comment: @Matthew PK That's not me, I just used SQL formatting tool before I posted the SQL here. There are no parenthesis in the actual SQL.

Comment: @Matthew PK No, no where clause at the moment (I want to figure why it's so slower in the view before adding where).

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql view performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760475/mysql-view-performance)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are performance problems with the way views are handled in MySql. Check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2760603/199220).

Basically there are 2 different algorithms that are used for views in MySql: Merge and Temptable. Merge usually performs quite well but Temptable can perform quite poorly. Merge cannot be used when the view contains certain constructs including `GROUP BY`, so your view would be using the Temptable algorithm.