# JOIN Performance Issue MySQL

Tags: mysql, nosql

I have a **MySQL DB View** which is having a **JOIN on 4 Tables** and all indexes have been used properly and previously response time was fair enough but as the database is growing rapidly, the **response time is gradually degrading**, so how can we **tune the performance**? I am new to solve this kind of complexity, Do I need to think about **database mirroring or partitioning or NoSQl** as well, if any doc can be supported on this, it would be very helpful in learning.

Comment: Start with `EXPLAIN`. This will help determine if there is a bottleneck with the *query*. Best before changing your architecture.

Comment: while using EXPLAIN, what factors tell us about the throttle limit? Can you tell more on this?

Comment: There are/were some limitations with MySQL views such that indexes would not be used.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760475/mysql-view-performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your retrieval/usage pattern, I advice to use `Partitioning` and **use the partition attribute in all join conditions and as first filter condition.**

Comment: Thanks, I'll go through the partitioning basics using following link
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Comment: @VardanGupta We have been using it successfully but in Oracle. Should be same in MySQL too. Do let me know, if any questions.

Comment: I'll get back to you, if further help needed, appreciated!